# do-while comparison in java

Tags: java, do-while

Assuming the role variable has been initialized, I need to know how to do that cycle is repeated while the variable role is different from any of those three strings through a `.equals()` as is normally done with a single string.

```
do {    
    System.out.println("Input role");
    System.out.println("Administrator / Client / User");
    role=reader.stringReader();
    role=role.toLowerCase();
} while (role!="administrator" || "client" || "user");
```

Comment: `while (role!="administrator" && role!="client" && role!="user");`

Comment: maybe something like:
`!(role.equals("administrator") || role.equals("....`
though maybe with the literal first for a little null safety...`"administrator".equals(role)`
or I'd load the values into a Set with a descriptive name and use `contains`.  Note the distributed inversion depending on where you want the negation.

Comment: @AlmightyR you need to use `.equals()`

Comment: @c0der when the OP doesn't put any effort into it...I don't feel like I need to either. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to check that `role!="administrator" && role!="client" && role!="user`  use:

```
   //role=role.toLowerCase();
} while ( ! role.equalsIgnoreCase("administrator") &&
          ! role.equalsIgnoreCase("client") &&
          ! role.equalsIgnoreCase("user")
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a method like this:

```
private static boolean isMatch(String input) {
  String[] goodInputs = new String[]{"administrator","client","users"};
  for (int i = 0; i < goodInputs.length; i++) {
    if (input.equals(goodInputs[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

then you code can look like this

```
do {    
  System.out.println("Input role");
  System.out.println("Administrator / Client / User");
  role=reader.stringReader();
  role=role.toLowerCase();
} while (!isMatch(role));
```

Comment: A small suggestion : move `.toLowerCase();` to `isMatch`. Up voted your suggestion.